# (RESUELTO) C# Función recursiva que permita obtener todos los números primos inferiores al valor informado por el usuario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, recursión

Desarrollar un programa que utilice una función recursiva que permita obtener todos los números primos inferiores al valor informado por el usuario.

Use un button = btnIniciar, un textBox para escribir el número mayor = txtNumero, y el listBox donde se agregan los primos = listadePrimos.

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 2;
            int _numero = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumero.Text);
            primos(_numero, x);         
        }
        void primos(int num, int x)
        {
            if (x < num)
            {
                if (x % 2 != 0 || x == 2)
                {
                    if (x % 3 != 0 || x == 3)
                    {
                        if (x % 5 != 0 || x == 5)
                        {
                            listadePrimos.Items.Add(x);
                        }
                    }
                }               
                primos(num, x + 1);         
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y luego usa las herramientas de búsqueda para saber si hay preguntas equivalentes a la tuya usa p.ej: `[c#] primos` notarás que hay quienes han tratado el problema con ligeros cambios de nombre. Si no pones la etiqueta de lenguaje y sólo pones `primos` te vas a encontrar algoritmos fantásticos en los que sólo es necesario adaptar la sintaxis al lenguaje.

Comment: No queda claro si tu problema es a) determinar si un número es primo o b) un problema de UI

Comment: Hola @CandidMoe, con el segundo intento que hice, se muestran todos los primos como dice la consigna del parcial, lo que no estoy seguro es si la función void primos se podría considerar recursividad

Comment: Si una función se llama a si misma, es recursiva. Basta mirar dentro del cuerpo para saberlo. Si, tu función `primos` es recursiva.

Comment: La solución va como respuesta y no en la pregunta, edita y corrige por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira aquí te voy a poner un algoritmo iterativo que hice hace ya algún tiempo:

```
public bool EsPrimo(int num)
{
    int raiz = Math.Sqrt(num);
    int cont = 2;
    bool esDivisible= false; 
    bool esPrimo = false;

    if(num == 2)
    { 
       esPrimo = true;
    } 
    else
    {
       while(cont <= raíz && esDivisible == false)
       {
          if(num % cont == 0)
          { 
             esDivisible = true;
          }
   
          cont++;
       }
    }

    if(esDivisible == false)
    {
       esPrimo = true;
    }

    return esPrimo;
}
```

Un ejemplo de llamada sería por ejemplo para saber los primos qué hay entre **2** y **100**:

```
for(int i = 2; i<= 100; i++)
{
   if(esPrimo(i))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(i.TiString() + " es primo);
   }
}
```